Problem authenticating with SSH on GitHub when pushing to remote repository
I'm having difficulty successfully authenticating to GitHub using SSH when trying to push to a remote repository. I've followed the steps to set up my SSH key and added it to my GitHub account, but I still can't authenticate correctly
When I try to push to my remote repository, I add the username and enter the passphrase of my SSH key when prompted for the password. However, I am getting a fatal error message
I have checked my SSH key settings, key file permissions, and my repository's remote URL, but the issue persists. Is there anything else I need to check or configure to resolve this issue?
I use linux
Username for 'https://github.com': Brianarguello
Password for 'https://Brianarguello@github.com':
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Autenticación falló para 'https://github.com/Brianarguello/pysave.git/'

use an ssh remote (git@ instead of https://)

I get the same error

may you tell us how did you added your ssh key file in github and how you changed remote url from https:// to git@, I'm sure the issue is in some step


When I try to push to my remote repository, I add the username and enter the passphrase of my SSH key when prompted for the password. However, I am getting a fatal error message

You didn't describe this process very well - but to me this sounds as if you're entering the passphrase where a password would be required (hence the message:

Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021

Instead launch your ssh-agent, add your git-hub identity to it ssh-add /path/to/private_key and try connecting.
